# Save map direction to My Places in Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to request a direction using direction services api of google map api version 3 and load that direction to my google account specifically to my places?

I need the references for that if possible :)

Answer (score 1):

My Places currently doesn't have an API, so no it isn't possible.